# GPIOs are put at 0.6 V during boot

Tags: raspbian, gpio, boot, webiopi

I have made a little project using WebIOPi, and it works like a charm. However, I have noticed that during the boot of the Raspberry Pi, all I/O pins are put at 0.6 V. This is enough to trigger my transistors and causes quite a lot of problems.

I am running the newest versions of WebIOPi and [Raspbian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspbian), using a ABElectronics IOPi Expander.

How do I control the Raspberry Pi's behaviour during boot or is there a workaround?

Comment: You could just add a/increase the size of the resistors on the base of the transistors to increase the voltage required to trigger them.

Answer (score 1):

The state of the GPIO during startup is undefined, but on boot all should be set as input. If Console I/O is enabled TxD & RxD (8 & 10) will be configured for serial IO. There are on-board 1.8KΩ pullup on I2C (3 & 5). If you need to define the state of other pins you should include pullup resistors.

Comment: I think pull-down would be more appropriate in this case, as pull-up would exacerbate the problem.